# LowLevelMouseProc callback function from a separate background thread

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, msdn

I have to update some pretty old MFC VC++ code to capture all mouse clicks via the  [SetWindowsHookEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) and the  [LowLevelMouseProc callback function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a background thread.  I'll then have to send a message back to my main thread indicating the click (this part I can already do).  The purpose of this is to have a timed lockout mechanism within the application if the user doesn't interact with it for a little while.
I cant seem to get the callback to function when in it's own thread though.  On its own I can get the SetWindowsHookEx and the LowLevelMouseProc to output the mouseclicks just fine, but when I try to do it in another thread, I get nothing.  I found this quote on the LowLevelMouseProc on MSDN:

> "This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop."

I have to put it in it's own thread so that it isn't blocking the rest of the program.

I've left out error checking out of my code for brevity.  I'm don't do a lot of C++ coding, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
void MouseMonitor::initialize()
{
    theInstance_ = new MouseMonitor();

    CWinThread* mouseThread = AfxBeginThread(WaitForPeek, NULL);    
}

UINT MouseMonitor::WaitForPeek(LPVOID lp)
{
    MSG msg;
    DWORD status;
    g_Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, &LowLevelMouseProc, 
                          GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    while (1)
        {
            while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
        } 
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc (int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        const char *msg;
        char msg_buff[128];
        msg = "";
        switch (wParam)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: msg = "WM_LBUTTONDOWN"; break;
        case WM_LBUTTONUP: msg = "WM_LBUTTONUP"; break;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: break;
        case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: msg = "WM_RBUTTONDOWN"; break;
        case WM_RBUTTONUP: msg = "WM_RBUTTONUP"; break;
        default: 
            sprintf(msg_buff, "Unknown msg: %u", wParam); 
            break;
    }
    if (msg != "")
    {
        TRACE("<<< MouseClick >>>\n");
        cout << msg << endl;
    }

}

return CallNextHookEx(g_Hook, code, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

Comment: Try adding `TranslateMessage()` to your message loop.  Also, use `GetMessage()` instead of `PeekMessage()`, or at least preceed it with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`, so the thread can sleep and not run an unyielding loop wasting CPU cycles when there are no messages to process.

Comment: Wow, that was really simple.  Thanks there Gambit.  I just replaced the PeekMessage with GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_MOUSEFIRST, WM_MOUSELAST).  Much appreciated.

Comment: You are trying **way** too hard. The standard implementation for a timed lockout is to set a timer, call [`GetLastInputInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302.aspx) in the `WM_TIMER` handler, and either reset the timer with the new remainder, or perform the lockout.